# How to start rpcbind automatically at boot on Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, start, linux

I have been unsuccessfully trying to configure my Ubuntu 14.04 server to start rpcbind on boot.
RPCbind is installed and works fine if I start it manually with
`service rpcbind start`
I have added the symlinks to the runlevel directories automatically using the command
`update-rc.d rpcbind defaults`
For the record, I tried other variations of the previous command, such as `update-rc.d rpcbind start 2345` and `update-rc.d rpcbind enable 2345`. None of them created the symlinks, only `update-rc.d rpcbind defaults` did.
Now, in my default runlevel, there is a symlink that looks like this:

```
S20rpcbind -> ../init.d/rpcbind
```

Even with this, when I reboot the server, rpcbind does not start automatically.
Any help to make this work will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You have to remove rcpbind-boot.override in /etc/init (look at Ubuntu upstart wiki)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found one way to do it that works. I simply added the command `service rpcbind start` inside the  `/etc/rc.local` script. 
I don't know if this is the proper way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Like Neo_999 says you can add stuff to your `/etc/rc.local` and for already declared services this works well.

For things without a service-declaration, you can fake it through GNU screen:

`sudo -u $USER -- screen -d -m $EXECUTABLE`

This let's you spawn a pre-detached screen-session with an arbitrary `$EXECUTABLE` running as `$USER`.

Hacky as heck, but it does work and saves you the trouble of writing init-scripts.